# Borel sets and statistics

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, borel-sets

I'm studying statistics and one of the passages that we use to transpose the study of probability implies the use of Borel sets... I can't understand exactly what they are and how they are useful in my case... Could someone explain these two things to me in a simple way?

Comment: Given a topological space $(X,\tau)$, the collection of Borel sets is just the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the topology $\tau$. In other words, it is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all of the open sets in $X$. When you deal formally with probability, you are talking about measure theory, and that's where $\sigma$-algebras come into play.

Comment: What is your background in measure theory, real analysis, topology, and/or probability? It's hard to give you a useful answer without knowing your level of mathematical knowledge.